# Unusual problem with eqnarray

Tags: arrays, displaystyle

I have this code that gives me two problems:

1. `y` and `x` are displayed incorrectly in the first and third row of
   the `eqnarray`, like if they had a `\rm` in front of them, why?
2. it gives me

   ```
   main.tex:91 Undefined control sequence.
   <argument> \D 
   ^0  
   l.91 \Gamma(\Dz
   (t)\to f)&=&\frac{1}{2}\rm{e}^{-\tau}\left|\Af\right|^2 \{ \l...
   The control sequence at the end of the top line
   of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
   misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
   ```

have I forgot to declare something? Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\title{ aaa }
\author{FLR }
\date{June 2011}
%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Packages to be used
%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage{amsfonts} %for integers using \mathbb{Z}
\usepackage{lineno}  % for line numbering during review
\usepackage{graphicx}  % to include figures (can also use other packages)
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig,booktabs}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xspace}     % 
% predefined symbold
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Adds a large collection of math symbols
\usepackage{ifthen} % for conditional statements
%\graphicspath{{./}} % Make Latex search fig subdir for figures
% %%%%%%% CHOOSE --------
\newboolean{pdflatex}
%\setboolean{pdflatex}{false} % use this if using eps figures
\setboolean{pdflatex}{true} % use this if using non-eps figures
%

\newboolean{articletitles}
\setboolean{articletitles}{true} % False removes titles in references

\newboolean{uprightparticles}
\setboolean{uprightparticles}{false} %Set to true to get roman particle symbols

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek} % Adds in support for greek letters in roman typeset

\usepackage{hyperref}    % Hyperlinks in references
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} % Internal hyperlinks to floats.
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\def\CP  {\ensuremath{C\!P}\xspace}
\def\CPV  {\ensuremath{C\!PV}\xspace}
\def\C  {\ensuremath{C}\xspace}
\def\P  {\ensuremath{P}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Ap}  {\ensuremath{{\cal A}_{\rm{P}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Apnoef}  {\ensuremath{{\cal A}_{\rm{P~no~eff}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Acp}  {\ensuremath{{\cal A}_{\rm{CP}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Araw}  {\ensuremath{{\cal A}_{\rm{RAW}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\AGamma}  {\ensuremath{{\cal A}_{\rm{\Gamma}}}\xspace} %
\newcommand{\Af}  {\ensuremath{{\cal A}_f}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Afb} {\ensuremath{\bar{\cal A}_f}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Am}  {\ensuremath{{\cal A}_m}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Adir}{\ensuremath{{\cal A}^{\rm dir}}\xspace}
\def\DDbar {\ensuremath{\kern -0.1em \stackrel{\kern 0.1em \textsf{\fontsize{5pt}{1em}\selectfont(---)}}{D}\kern -0.3em}\xspace}
\def\Dz{\ensuremath{\D^0}\xspace}
\begin{document}

\maketitle



% (4) %
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eq:p-1}
\Gamma(\Dz(t)\to f)&=&\frac{1}{2}\rm{e}^{-\tau}\left|\Af\right|^2 
\{\left(1+|\lambda_f|^2\right)\cosh(y\tau)+\left(1- |\lambda_f|^2\right)\cos(x\tau)\nonumber\\
&+&2\Re(\lambda_f)\sinh(y\tau)-2\Im(\lambda_f)\sin(x\tau)\},\nonumber\\
\Gamma(b(t)\to f)&=&\frac{1}{2}\rm{e}^{-\tau}\left|\bar\Af\right|^2 
\{\left(1+|\lambda^{-1}_f|^2\right)\cosh(y\tau)+\left(1- |\lambda^{-1}_f|^2\right)\cos(x\tau)\nonumber\\
&+&2\Re(\lambda^{-1}_f)\sinh(y\tau)-2\Im(\lambda^{-1}_f)\sin(x\tau)\},
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would appear that the control sequence `\D` isn't defined.

Comment: Use `\def\Dz{\ensuremath{D^0}\xspace}`. Note `{D^0}` instead of `{\D^0}`. As a side note don't use `eqnarray`. Use `align` or `align*` from `amsmath`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title of your posting suggests that you're encountering problems with the `eqnarray` environment. Actually, neither of the problems is related to `eqnarray` directly.

- The term `\D` in the definition of `\Dz` should really be just `D`, right?
- The reason why the terms `x` and `y` in the original form of your example show up in upright rather than math-italic form is that `\rm` does *not* take an argument. The command `\rm` is a *switch*, i.e., all letters in the current group following `\rm` will get typeset in the upright-roman font shape; this group does not end with the `}` after `{e}`. What makes the issue a bit difficult to diagnose at first is that there are only three (latin) letters on the first and third lines subject to the action of `\rm`: `e`, `x`, and `y`; all other material is either a symbol (e.g., a parenthesis), a greek symbol, or gets typeset in upright roman form anyway because it's a math operator (e.g., `cosh`). Use either `\mathrm{e}` or `\text{e}`, and the problem goes away.

Note that your code features a number of issues that, collectively, make it both difficult to read and debug and less than typographically satisfactory.

- Don't use the heavily deprecated and typographically suspect `eqnarray` environment. Use the `align` environment instead; it's an environment provided by the `amsmath` package, which is already loaded in your code. In case you harbor any doubts about the inferiority of `eqnarray`, please read the posting [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) and the associated answers.
- The second and fourth lines should be indented quite a bit relative to the first and third lines; do not align the `=` sign of the first and third lines with the `+` symbols of the second and fourth lines.
- A number of packages get loaded more than once. Sooner or later this is going to cause trouble.
- Don't use the deprecated `\rm` and `\cal` directives in math mode. Use `\text{...}` and `\mathcal{...}` instead.
- The many `\xspace` directives don't do anything at all in math mode. Omit them entirely.
- The use of `\left` and `\right` to influence the size of the parentheses leads to unevenly-sized parentheses across (logically) related terms. Better to use `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead -- at least in the case of the equations at hand. Also, use `\Big` (note the uppercase `B`) to set the sizes of the curly braces -- they really need to be bigger than any of the round parentheses.

With these issues addressed, and the preamble simplified to make it more of a *minimal* working example, one gets this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek} % Adds in support for greek letters in roman typeset

\def\CP  {\ensuremath{C\!P}}
\def\CPV  {\ensuremath{C\!PV}}
\def\C  {\ensuremath{C}}
\def\P  {\ensuremath{P}}
\newcommand{\Ap}  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}_{\text{P}}}}
\newcommand{\Apnoef}  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}_{\text{P~no~eff}}}}
\newcommand{\Acp}  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}_{\text{CP}}}}
\newcommand{\Araw}  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}_{\text{RAW}}}}
\newcommand{\AGamma}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}_{\Gamma}}} %
\newcommand{\Af}  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}_f}}
\newcommand{\Afb} {\ensuremath{\bar\mathcal{A}_f}}
\newcommand{\Am}  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}_m}}
\newcommand{\Adir}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}^{\text{dir}}}}
\def\DDbar {\ensuremath{\kern -0.1em \stackrel{\kern 0.1em 
       \textsf{\fontsize{5pt}{1em}\selectfont(---)}}{D}\kern -0.3em}}
\def\Dz{\ensuremath{D^0}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{eq:p-1}
\Gamma(\Dz(t)\to f)
&=\frac{1}{2}\text{e}^{-\tau}\bigl|\Af\bigr|^2 \Big\{     
  \bigl(1+|\lambda_f|^2\bigr)\cosh(y\tau)+
  \bigl(1-|\lambda_f|^2\bigr)\cos(x\tau)\nonumber\\
&\qquad +2\Re(\lambda_f)\sinh(y\tau)-2\Im(\lambda_f)\sin(x\tau)
  \Big\},\nonumber\\
\Gamma(b(t)\to f)
&=\frac{1}{2}\text{e}^{-\tau}\bigl|\bar\Af\bigr|^2 \Big\{ 
  \bigl(1+|\lambda^{-1}_f|^2\bigr)\cosh(y\tau)+
  \bigl(1-|\lambda^{-1}_f|^2\bigr)\cos(x\tau)\nonumber\\
&\qquad +2\Re(\lambda^{-1}_f)\sinh(y\tau)-2\Im(\lambda^{-1}_f)
  \sin(x\tau)\Big\}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `\mathrm` or `\textnormal` instead of `\text` for textual sub/superscripts. All those `\ensuremath` commands are useless, since these commands are to be used in math mode; I wouldn't recommend using `\def`. And `\bar\mathcal{A}_f` is wrong: `\bar{\mathcal{A}}_f` will do right.

Comment: @egreg - I had noticed the `\bar\mathcal{A}_f` as well. However, it doesn't throw an error in the present example and even creates the same output as `\bar{\mathcal{A}}_f`, so I decided to omit from the litany of things the OP really should address.